# libgdx Table can't get ChangeListener for a click to fire?

Tags: libgdx

I have a table added to a stage, and I can't get a click listener to fire for it:

```
Table table = new Table();
table.setX(0);
table.setY(0);
table.setWidth(300);
table.setHeight(300);
table.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        System.out.println("click");
    }
});

stage.addActor(table);
```

I've set a background nine patch on the table, and it's rendering just fine. Clicking has no effect. If I add something like a label or a button to the table, then set the same ChangeListener to those widgets, the listener fires just fine.

Is there some special handling that Table needs for this to work?

Thanks

--------- Update -------------------

The only way I could get this to work was by using an EventListener to block all interaction on the Table instance:

```
table.addListener(new EventListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean handle(Event event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

All the events would fire as expected here.

I also tried setting the table to touchable, but still the ChangeListener would not fire:

```
table.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
table.setListener(....);
```

So I guess I'm going to stick with the EventListener approach.

Answer (score 5):

The `Table` in libgdx is not `touchable` by default, in its constructor `setTouchable(Touchable.childrenOnly);`(Take a look at the [source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Table.java#L90)) is called, which means, that this `Actor` (the `Table´) won't get any input events, but its children will (Look at the [javadoc](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Touchable.html#childrenOnly)).

So to enable input events for the `Table` and not only for its children, you need to call `setTouchable(Touchable.enabled)`.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: This still didn't work for me. The only way I can make this happen is if I add an EventListener to the panel, then return 'true' for the handle() method. Updated answer above.

Comment: @user3203425 i just had a look at the question again and i noticed, that you are using `ChangeListener`. Why don't you add a `ClickListener`? If you use `ClickListener` instead of `ChangeListener`, and you call `setTocuhable(true)`, i guess, the click-events will get fired and the `Table` will notice them.